# Report Builder Expressions Help Sum three fields then divide by 5

Tags: expression, reportbuilder3.0

I currently have three columns in report builder that look like this.

PU           PI     LO   Total SUM
0            13     31        44

The Total Sum column is an expression that sums the first three columns with =Fields!Put_Away.Value+Fields!Picked.Value+Fields!Loaded.Value.  I now want to create one more column that grabs the sum of of those three fields and divides it by 5.  How do I do this? I tried =Fields!PU.Value+Fields!PI.Value+Fields!LO.Value/5 but it gives me 19.2 as the result of the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets.

Currently you are doing `=Fields!Put_Away.Value+Fields!Picked.Value+Fields!Loaded.Value/5`, which converts to `0 + 13 + 31 / 5`, or if we include the inferred brackets, `0 + 13 + (31/5)`.

You want `=(Fields!Put_Away.Value+Fields!Picked.Value+Fields!Loaded.Value)/5`, which becomes `(0 + 13 + 31)/5`